# How to print a input phrase N times, each time on a different line on python?

Tags: python

How can I read an integer (integer) from the user, and read a phrase (phrase) from the user.  Then print the phrase (integer) times, each time on a different line?

This is what I have so far:

```
integer = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
phrase = str(input("Please enter a phrase: "))
ans = integer * phrase
print(ans)
```

This only prints the phrase however many times on a single line, how can I separate prints "hellow" in different lines rather instead of "hello,hello,hello"

Answer (score 1):

you probably want something like:

```
integer = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
phrase = str(input("Please enter a phrase: "))
for _ in range(integer):
    print(phrase)
```

I use `_` here to denote a throwaway variable because you're not actually using it anywhere, you're just iterating `integer` times.

You could also just append a newline character to your `phrase` and call `print` a single time like this:

```
ans = (phrase + '\n') * integer
print(ans)
```